# complex conjugated amplitude response

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-transform

This question arises actually from electrical engineering but I think it is not hard-bounded to it and the math itself isn't much special anyway, I guess? So my question is:

There is a function $ u(t) = A \cdot e^{(-at)} $ and you have to apply a Fourier transformation which results in $ U(jw) = \frac{A}{a+jw} $. Up to here everything is fine and I get it. Next task is to determine the so-called amplitude response $ |U(jw)| $.

What I know is the following:

$ x_Z(jw) = | x_Z(jw) | \cdot e^{j \Phi_Z (w)} $ and
$ x_N(jw) = | x_N(jw) | \cdot e^{j \Phi_N (w)} $ and together you'd have:
$ x(jw) = \frac{| x_Z(jw) |}{| x_N(jw) |} = | x(jw) | \cdot e^{j \Phi (w)} $

This should be applied somehow (I guess, I'm not sure) to $ U(jw) $ above and yield:

$ x(jw) = \frac{A}{a+jw} = \frac{A}{\sqrt{a^2 + w^2} \cdot e^{jarctan \Phi (\frac{w}{a})}}  $

I don't understand this lest step. How do I get from $ x(jw) = \frac{A}{a+jw} $ to $ x(jw) = \frac{A}{\sqrt{a^2 + w^2} \cdot e^{jarctan \Phi (\frac{w}{a})}}  $ ?

edit: Following up on Eric's answer my question is then:
How do I know what $ x $ and $ y $ are in $ U(jw) = \frac{A}{a+jw} $ ?
I guess it is $ x = a $ and $ y = w $ but what about the $ A$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a$ and $w$ (possibly $\omega$ in the original?) are real numbers, so $|a + \mathrm{j}w| = \sqrt{a^2 + w^2}$ by the Pythagorean theorem.  Then $\arg(a + \mathrm{j}w)$ is either $\arctan(w/a)$ or $\pi + \arctan(w/a)$ (depending on which quadrant $a + \mathrm{j}w$ is in, which is the job being performed by $\Phi$) for most $a$ and $w$.  Really, what is being done is converting a complex number in Cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates.  See [polar complex plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_complex_plane) for more details.  (The arctangent used at the Wikipedia article is a little sneaky, to avoid having to work out quadrants.  You can imagine that $\Phi$ is here to implement equivalent sneakiness.)

---

So we have $u(t) = A \mathrm{e}^{-at}$.  The Laplace transform of $u(t)$ is $U(\mathrm{j}w) = \frac{A}{a + \mathrm{j}w}$.  We want to split this into its magnitude part and angle part.  The numerator is a real number so
$$
A = \begin{cases}|A| \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{j} 0} ,& A \geq 0  \\
|A| \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{j} \pi} ,& A < 0
\end{cases}
$$
With that, we're ready to work out the polar form of $U(wt)$.  First we break the numerator into its polar form and do the same to the denominator.
\begin{align*}
U(wt) &= \frac{A}{a+wt}  \\
    &= \begin{cases}
\frac{|A|\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{j} 0}}{\sqrt{a^2 + w^2} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{j} \arctan \Phi(w/a)}} ,& A \geq 0  \\ 
\frac{|A|\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{j} \pi}}{\sqrt{a^2 + w^2} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{j} \arctan \Phi(w/a)}} ,& A < 0 
\end{cases}  \\
    &= \begin{cases}
\frac{|A|}{\sqrt{a^2 + w^2}} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{j} 0}}{ \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{j} \arctan \Phi(w/a)}} ,& A \geq 0  \\ 
\frac{|A|}{\sqrt{a^2 + w^2}}\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{j} \pi}}{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{j} \arctan \Phi(w/a)}} ,& A < 0 
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
From here we can see that for either sign of $A$, the magnitude of $U$ is $\frac{|A|}{\sqrt{a^2 + w^2}}$.  (And the angle is something a little complicated, either $- \arctan \Phi(w/a)$ or $\pi - \arctan \Phi(w/a)$, that depends on the sign of $A$.  If we already knew $A > 0$, then the case for negative $A$ is unneeded.)

Comment: Thanks, for me, this means I wouldn't need the first given expressions, I could, more or less, just read it? And that everything happens as a denominator is obvious?

Comment: @Ben : We're replacing "$a+ \mathrm{j}w$" in the denominator with exactly the same thing, just expressed in polar coordinates, so if you're used to that, not much is happening when $x(jw)$ is rewritten that way.  The numerator is the real number $A$, the scalar in the given $u(t)$ -- the Laplace transform of $\mathrm{e}^{-a t}$ is $\frac{1}{a + \mathrm{j}w}$ and multiplication by the constant $A$ flows through by linearity of the Laplace transform.  I'll add a little bit about finding the amplitude response...

Comment: Thank you! So the $A$ is just a constant which has to be considered/not to be forgotten? Then, I think, I got it. Thank you! Nevertheless, I'm grateful for any further input :) E.g., what is the Laplace transformation, and what is it doing, here?

Comment: @Ben : So a funny thing...  The Laplace transform and the Fourier transform are very closely related.  Not being too careful about whether the forward or inverse transforms have multliples of $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$, the Laplace transform evaluated at an imaginary frequency, $\mathrm{j} \omega$, is the Fourier transform evaluated at the real frequency $\omega$.  So what is being done is a Fourier transform -- decomposition of the original $u(t)$ into sinusoidal components.  It's just being done using real numbers in the transform so that the complex stuff is delayed to the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input! I will go through it carefully, thus, so far, thanks again!